# How to return sum of row values based on # of missing values in defined columns in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, sum

I am trying to perform this algorithm in R:

Data name: EPIC_26

For columns 1 to 6, if there are only 1 missing values, sum the remaining 5 rows values to form another column, if there are more than 1 missing values, return missing/na as a result for that column.

I assume that I have to perform the following criterion to get to my result, calculate the number of missing values per row for columns 1 to 6, if it is 0, sum all 6 values; if it is 1, ignore that missing value and sum all other 5; else if it is more than 1, return missing.

I have tried is.na() function but I do not know how to select defined columns for my data. Please help me with this question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please update your description with proper formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first create a new variable to count the amount of `NA`, and then use a simple `ifelse()` condition:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(NA, 1:5),
                 v2 = c(NA, NA, 2:5),
                 v3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3:5),
                 v4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4:5),
                 v5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5),
                 v6 = rep(NA, 6)
)

> df
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2  1 NA NA NA NA NA
3  2  2 NA NA NA NA
4  3  3  3 NA NA NA
5  4  4  4  4 NA NA
6  5  5  5  5  5 NA

df$new <- rowSums(is.na(df[1:6]))

df$new2 <- ifelse(df$new < 2, rowSums(df[1:6], na.rm = TRUE), NA)

> df
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 new new2
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA   6   NA
2  1 NA NA NA NA NA   5   NA
3  2  2 NA NA NA NA   4   NA
4  3  3  3 NA NA NA   3   NA
5  4  4  4  4 NA NA   2   NA
6  5  5  5  5  5 NA   1   25
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful!